# Doctrine Blameable: on="change" doesn't work while on="create" and "update" do

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to combine Doctrine's Extensions Blameable and Softdeleteable: when I execute `$em->remove($myEntity);`, I want to get the fields `deleted` and `deletedBy` updated accordingly.

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deleted", timeAware=false)
 */

[...]

/**
 * DateTime of softdeletion
 * @var \DateTime
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="deleted", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */
private $deleted;

/**
 * Softdeleted by
 * @var MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\User $deletedBy
 *
 * @Gedmo\Blameable(on="change", field="deleted")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn()
 */
private $deletedBy;
```

I have a similar configuration for created/createdBy (with `Blameable(on="create")`) and updated/updatedBy (with `Blameable(on="update")`).

Even weirder, if I replace the code above by the one below, the field `deletedBy` is correctly updated:

```
/**
 * Softdeleted by
 * @var MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\User $deletedBy
 *
 * @Gedmo\Blameable(on="update")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn()
 */
private $deletedBy;
```

So it seems that it is only the `Blameable(on="change", field="deleted")` part which doesn't work, and I have no idea why...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275217/doctrine-blameable-extension-on-change-doesnt-work/28469709#28469709